# List recursion?

Tags: python, list, recursion, permutation

I wrote a function:

```
def expandList(aList):
    """expand a list"""

    finalList = []

    for j in aList:
        tempList = []

        if type(j) != type(list):
            tempList.append(j)
            finalList.extend(tempList)

        else:
            finalList.extend(expandList(j))

    return finalList
```

to expand nested list within themselves like:

```
[[1, [2, 3], [3, 2]], [2, [1, 3], [3, 1]], [3, [1, 2], [2, 1]]]
```

into:

```
[[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3], [2,3,1], [3,1,2], [3,2,1]]
```

or

```
    [[1, [2, [3, 4], [4, 3]], [3, [2, 4], [4, 2]], [4, [2, 3], [3, 2]]], 
[2, [1, [3, 4], [4, 3]], [3, [1, 4], [4, 1]], [4, [1, 3], [3, 1]]], 
[3, [1, [2, 4], [4, 2]], [2, [1, 4], [4, 1]], [4, [1, 2], [2, 1]]], 
[4, [1, [2, 3], [3, 2]], [2, [1, 3], [3, 1]], [3, [1, 2], [2, 1]]]]
```

into:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 4, 3],[1, 3, 2, 4],
[1, 3, 4, 2],[1, 4, 3, 2],[1, 4, 2, 3],[2, 1, 3, 4],
[2, 1, 4, 3],[2, 3, 1, 4],[2, 3, 4, 1],[2, 4, 1, 3],
[2, 4, 3, 1],[3, 1, 2, 4],[3, 1, 4, 2],[3, 2, 1, 4],
[3, 2, 4, 1],[3, 4, 1, 2],[3, 4, 2, 1],[4, 1, 2, 3],
[4, 1, 3, 2],[4, 2, 1, 3],[4, 2, 3, 1],[4, 3, 1, 2], 
[4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

and so forth. I wish to be able to do this in any size of nested lists.

---

My function doesn't seem to work right. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix/improve my function?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please don't use camelCase in Python code. The preferred style for anything besides class names (where CamelCase is used) is `snake_case`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Ah got it. I just started python pretty recently so I'm still new to the styling format and other manipulation. I will keep that in mind next time I write a program. Thank you!

Comment: There is limit in using depth of recursion in python

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what you are trying to do. It seems the code is not doing any thing at all. If replaced the `type(j) != type(list)` with `not isinstance(j, list)` it will produce a flat list. Could you clarify that the none  list item is the first item always and it needs to be extended as list with other two items which they are lists?

Answer (score 0):

First of all using following command is a wrong way for checking the list type :

```
type(j) != type(list)
```

because `type(list)` returns `<type 'type'>` actually you are getting the type of a type object that is a `type`.

In edition you don't need to loop over your sub list and using `extend` method although you used it incorrect.Since your numbers are in the first index you can just convert it to list and append the rest to it.

You can use a simple list comprehension :

```
>>> [[[i[0]]+j for j in i[1:]] for i in l]
[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2]], [[2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1]], [[3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]]
```

Comment: For the list comprehension, would that work for all list size or do I have to apply a recursion to a bigger list?

Comment: @TriNguyen It will works for any length of array just if you have the number in first index.